# How to change Magento Enterprise "sort by price" to descending?

Tags: magento, sorting

I've played with this block a bit in toolbar.phtml:

```
<div class="sort-by">
        <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
        <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
        <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
            **<?php if($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?>**
            <a class="category-desc v-middle" href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?></a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <a class="category-asc v-middle" href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'desc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

I changed asc to desc, but it doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: Are you trying to change the default sort order?  Modifying the toolbar won't change the default sort order.  It's only a mechanism to set the sort order when the user interacts with it.

Comment: public function setDefaultOrder($field)
    {
        if (isset($this->_availableOrder[$field])) {
            $this->_orderField = $field;
        }
        return $this;
    }  I tried playing with this function

Comment: id ideally like to just globally change all sorts to default ->price -> descending

Comment: Exactly what page you are trying to change the sort order on?  Is this frontend or backend, and is it the order history page?

Comment: I'm trying to change it on the frontend->category

Answer (score 2):

Magento currently doesn't let you define the sort order from the backend configuration.  They let you choose what you can sort by, however.  To change the default sort order, you must do the following:

1. Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php`  to
   `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php`
2. Open `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Product/Block/List/Toolbar.php`
3. Look for `protected $_direction           = 'asc';`
4. Change to `protected $_direction           = 'desc';`
5. Save the file, clear caches.

To change the default sort by to Price, do the following:

1. In the Magento Admin, Go to `System > Configuration > Catalog`
2. Change **Product Listing Sort by** to **Price**
3. Click **Save Config**

Comment: Hey thanks man this works.  But its app/code/local/mage/catalog/block/product/list/toolbar.php

Comment: You should create a custom module (in `app/code/local`), extend the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` class, and only override the `$_direction` attribute, instead of overriding the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

In catalog.xml add value:

```
<action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
```

example:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
     <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
      <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
     <!-- .... -->
     <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
     </block>
```